# Apache2: serve page from another IP address

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Please bear with me while I try to explain some htaccess gymnastics I'd like to perform.

I have this domain: `eamorr.somesite.com`, at 192.168.100.100.

It is serving pages from my `public_html` folder as expected.

Now, I want to use the following address:

`www.somesite.com/eamorr`

I do not have control over `www.somesite.com` (192.168.99.99), however my sysadmin has allowed me to place a `.htaccess` file in the `eamorr` folder. I am not allowed, under any circumstances, to place anything else in the `eamorr` folder for reasons I do not know.

What I want to happen is this:

User navigates to `www.somesite.com/eamorr/some_page.php`

User is fed `some_page.php` from `eamorr.somesite.com/some_page.php` (i.e. 192.168.100.100/some_page.php).

I'd like this to be as seamless as possible -- i.e. when a user navigates to http://www.somesite.com/eamorr/some_page.php they get served some_page.php and are oblivious to the fact that some_page is coming from a different server (192.168.100.100)

http://www.somesite.com/eamorr should be in the address bar of the user's browser at all times and not http://eamorr.somesite.com -- my boss "just wants it that way"...

Is this possible to do using `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is what is called a "reverse proxy", and it's a job for Apache's [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).  However, you can't set this up in a `.htaccess` file -- it has to be done in a different context.  Perhaps someone here knows better, but I don't think what you're asking for will be possible with a single `.htaccess` file alone.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache `mod_proxy` to point to another server. Apache docs [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html).

This worked well:

```
ProxyPass /blog http://blog.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.example.com/
```

But only after the proxy modules were loaded correctly:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

#### Notes

- Because of CloudFlare I also had to host the blog from a different hostname, not `*.example.com`.
- I added `Disallow: /` to my `blog.example.com/robots.txt`.  Like this search engines will not start indexing in two locations. And search engines will simply ignore `blog/robots.txt`.